snowflake managed iceberg table creation
I have gone through the snowflake documentation, I have still doubts could you help on this
Basically my use case is , ingesting large amount of a data by using copy command from s3 to snowflake in more than 100 terabytes, currently we are thinking to use iceberg tables which helps in reduce computation cost and storage cost , basically we don't want to use copy command and all is is it possible directly we can create the snowflake managed iceberg table on top of s3 bucket input data files and its mandatory to have parquet files as input ????
if the answer was i have the below questions regarding external volume and table creation:
Regarding the External volume creation the STORAGE_BASE_URL is for storing the iceberg metadata and all or can we mention where the input data files are located s3 bucket path
CREATE OR REPLACE EXTERNAL VOLUME exvol
STORAGE_LOCATIONS =((NAME = 'my-s3-us-west-2'
STORAGE_PROVIDER = 'S3'
STORAGE_BASE_URL = 's3://MY_EXAMPLE_BUCKET/' "
STORAGE_AWS_ROLE_ARN = 'arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/myrole'));

Regarding the iceberg table creation for the external volume we can mention external volume path what we created above for the base url what we mentioned is it for aws s3 bucket files
iceberg table creation:
CREATE OR REPLACE ICEBERG TABLE my_iceberg_table (
boolean_col boolean,
int_col int,
long_col long,
float_col float,
double_col double,
decimal_col decimal(10,5),
string_col string,
fixed_col fixed(10),
binary_col binary,
date_col date,
time_col time,
timestamp_ntz_col timestamp_ntz(6),
timestamp_ltz_col timestamp_ltz(6)
)
CATALOG = 'SNOWFLAKE'
EXTERNAL_VOLUME = 'my_ext_vol'
BASE_LOCATION = 'my/relative/path/from/extvol';

Basically my use case is , ingesting large amount of a data by using copy command from s3 to snowflake in more than 100 terabytes, currently we are thinking to use iceberg tables which helps in reduce computation cost and storage cost , basically we don't want to use copy command and all is is it possible directly we can create the snowflake managed iceberg table on top of s3 bucket input data files and its mandatory to have parquet files as input ????

Snowflake requires files to be in parquet format if you’re going to create Iceberg tables on top of them. Have you compared the capabilities of Iceberg tables v. External tables and determined that Iceberg tables are a better fit for your use cases?

I have tried with external tables also but its giving the poor performance and it takes more than 3 times what copy command takes time , it increase the compute cost giving less performance ???
could you provide the inputs where we need to mention the folder path for input files i have mentioned the ddls for volume creation and iceberg tables creation

I’m not sure what you mean by the folder path for input files? Your DDL already has the BASE_LOCATION parameter that references your file location

Thanks nic for the reply
my doubt was we need to mention the base location , as per my understand we are mentioning it for store the metadata and writes the data into same folder
but my doubt all for we have to create the iceberg table on top s3 files (where all the input data files are the) , that folder path where should we mention it??
my understanding was we are creating the external volume  to store the metadata of iceberg tables, please correct me if my understand was wrong

2 steps:

First you will need to convert those Parquet files into Iceberg. You currently can't do this within Snowflake (but stay tuned).

Future "Parquet Direct" in Snowflake (https://www.reddit.com/r/snowflake/comments/1brfhrn/can_we_create_snowflake_iceberg_tables_directly/kx9gbap/)
Today using Iceberg's add_files or migrate (https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/migrate-an-existing-data-lake-to-a-transactional-data-lake-using-apache-iceberg/).


Once you have these Parquet files converted into Iceberg, then you can convert to managed in Snowflake (https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/tables-iceberg-conversion)


